# Close modal dialog when no Close button

Tags: modal-dialog

I've made a mistake by creating a modal dialog in CEWP code without a Close button. Now I have no way of closing the modal and so cannot access the page or edit the code in web part.

I would of course copy the code but I can't get at it.
Similar to this post: http://blog.solutions2share.net/2013/05/spuimodaldialogshowmodaldialog-do-not.html

I've tried:

- I renamed the file ref'd in URL, but when I 'Edit Page' the dialog shows `Page cannot be found`.
- I've downloaded the Home.aspx with the CEWP but cannot see any reference to it in the code.

Is it possible to run a command in Developer Tools to close it?

Comment: Would you want to remove the `CEWP` from the page it self

Comment: Open the page in designer and you could edit the CEWP code there or atleast remove the CEWP from the page

Comment: All, thanks, but you miss the obvious - I cannot edit the page because the dialog is in the way. Solution below.

Answer (score 3):

So, if you should find yourself doing such a silly thing as above, you can remove the dialog (`it works in IE 11`) by bringing up Developer Tools and entering the following in DOM Explorer command line at the bottom:

```
SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(SP.UI.DialogResult.cancel)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just add `?contents=1` to your url and then remove the content editor web part from there.

Then i would recommend to place your code in a txt file and link it to the CEWP instead, then you can just delete the txt file if you wanna get rid of whatever it does and there is no risk of breaking the page/site itself.

[Which Webpart is that?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/124912/which-webpart-is-that/124915#124915)